Can set breakpoints in .js files in vscode only after started vite debugger?
Why I can only set valid breakpoints in .js files in vscode AFTER starting the vite (node.js) debugger?
Not working:

npx vite (starting the server)
Set breakpoint in vscode
Start Debugger with F5
New chrome window opens

Debugger does start but not react, only stoppable
Working:

npx vite (starting the server)
Start Debugger with F5
Set breakpoint in vscode
New chrome window opens

Debugger stopps at breakpoint and variables are visible. But with this methode I can only debug functions which are called after all initialisations?
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dns from 'dns'

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'dist',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: 'js/main.js',
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'bundle.js',
                assetFileNames: false,
            },
        },
        sourcemap: false
    },
    publicDir: false,
    css: false,
});

// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "enableContentValidation": false,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*",
                "webpack:///js/*": "${workspaceFolder}/js/*"
            },
            "trace": true
        }
    ]
}

Any idea? Thanks...
